# Multiline textbox with skype like Functionalities

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I was trying to have a textbox that creates new line when `Shift+Enter` is pressed and we can get keyevents when `Enter` is pressed
on backend of `KeyDown` Event i want to note that if `Enter` is pressed then do something.

```
if (e.Key.Equals(Key.RightShift))
            {
}
```

this works fine for single line.as far as i click `AcceptReturn = true` and `textwrapping` to `wrap` then on pressing `Enter` new line is added to textbox but the `event does not fire up.`

i want new line to happen at `Shift+Enter`

and on `Enter` event should fire.
any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably need to handle the **PreviewKeyDown** event. Catch the keypress combination you want to handle, handle it, then set `e.Handled = true` to make sure it doesn't get handled anywhere else as the keypress event [tunnels & bubbles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies).

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"
    PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_PreviewKeyDown" />
```

**Code-behind:**

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.None && e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        // Do your special enter handling here...
    }

    // Shift+Enter (and any other keys) will be handled as normally...
    // ...you'll still get your new line on Shift+Enter
}
```

**Note:** If you want an Enter keypress to still add a new line **as well** as your special handling then just remove the `e.Handled = true` line.

Comment: Simple enter did not worked i had to enter control modifierkey.if single enter is pressed event does not fires

Comment: @Lagrangian - It worked for me...unless I've misunderstood what you're trying to do. Which event doesn't fire? Does it go into the PreviewKeyDown handler?  Maybe you could post some more code in your question and we'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following on the KeyDown event, should work on a vanilla multiline textbox, no need for anything further:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Shift && e.KeyValue == (int)Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

            // Fire my custom event
        }
    }
```